# require is not defined? ephemeris

Tags: node.js

Browser showing require is not defined? for the follwing

`const ephemeris = require('ephemeris');`

This is my package.json

```
`{
  "dependencies": {
    "ephemeris": "^2.0.0"
  }
 
}`
```

solution for this problem

Comment: `require` is not meant to be used in browser only in node.js